# MirrorMaker2 only replicating about 1/3 of the data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am configuring MirrorMaker2 for disaster recovery. I have a primary Kafka and want to replicate to the secondary.

MirrorMaker2 is working, but is only replicating about 1/3 of the data to the target.

I have replication.factor=3 in my mm2.properties file to make the source and target topic configurations match.

Below is my full mm2.properties file. I'm really stuck on how to investigate and resolve, so thanks for any help.

```
clusters = source, target
source.bootstrap.servers = PLAINTEXT://private-kafka-main.cdp1-needle.data-dev.guidewire.net:31000
target.bootstrap.servers = PLAINTEXT://private-kafka-main.cdp1-butterfly.data-dev.guidewire.net:31000
source->target.enabled = true
source->target.topics = t.guidewire.0.cdp-dr-poc.09cb0bf677c247319e24f37079ad3805.pg
target->source.enabled = false

groups = mm2topic
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
auto.offset.reset=latest
replication.factor=3
```

Additional Information:

I found this error. There is, in fact, No Authorizer. In any case, if it's and authorization problem, I don't see why some messages would work.

```
Jul 19 14:38:19 ip-10-120-83-228 mm2: [2022-07-19 14:38:19,618] INFO refreshing consumer groups took 302 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.Scheduler:95)
Jul 19 14:38:20 ip-10-120-83-228 mm2: [2022-07-19 14:38:20,128] ERROR Scheduler for MirrorSourceConnector caught exception in scheduled task: syncing topic ACLs (org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.Scheduler:102)
Jul 19 14:38:20 ip-10-120-83-228 mm2: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SecurityDisabledException: No Authorizer is configured on the broker
...
Jul 19 14:38:20 ip-10-120-83-228 mm2: at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector.listTopicAclBindings(MirrorSourceConnector.java:353)
Jul 19 14:38:20 ip-10-120-83-228 mm2: at org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector.syncTopicAcls(MirrorSourceConnector.java:286)
```

Comment: Please clarify "about a third". You mean for every 3 records in the source, only one is in the target? Are there any logs that might indicate a problem?

Comment: Yes, for every 3 records in the source, only one in the target.

I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for in the logs, but I will check. Should have done this anyway!

Comment: One example could be that the source cluster /topic was configured to allow messages above 1MB, and some records are below that size. The target cluster/topic wasn't configured this way, so it's rejecting larger payloads

Comment: Thanks for the idea @OneCricketeer!

I'm generating test data, so all the messages are small. Less than 1kbyte.

Still working on fully analyzing the logs.

Comment: I added additional information with the only error message I found.

Comment: If there are no topic ACLs, I'd say that's a transient error

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Kafka & MirrorMaker were working correctly all the time!

We proved this was the case by using commands like the following in both regions:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 > messages.bin
```

The data was encoded, so the data captured was not that easy to work with. Still, we were able to parse the data and extract enough to compare the two streams.

Now that we know Kafka and MirrorMaker are solid, we can investigate how things are going wrong with our downstream Kafka consumer and other components.